# Initial help with official "create a block" tutorial

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

**[EDIT] Problem 3 is solved (just I must to remove `source: 'text'` from attributes declaration to allow store data in the  the block’s comment delimiter).**

Following [this tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/create-block/) I made a plugin for embed peertube video. My block is as simple as two fields (instance and ID). [Here it is a working example](https://telmo.club/projects/prueba-peertube/). And [here](https://github.com/aitormendez/peertube) the plugin.

I have three problems:

1. The TextControl fields are shown 100% wide, instead center in the column:

[image: The TextControl fields are shown 100% wide, instead center in the column]

2. Once created, I can not remove the block in the editor
3. The block shows the video content in the front end but when I come back to the editor, the fields are not stored. First is shown this:

[image]

Second, if I try to recover block with this button, the fields are shown empty (as in the first image).

This is the edit function (also [here](https://github.com/aitormendez/peertube/blob/master/src/edit.js#L34-L49) in context):

```
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';

export default function Edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
    return (
        <div className={ className }>
            <TextControl
                label={ __( 'Identificador', 'peertube' ) }
                value={ attributes.identificador }
                onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { identificador: val } ) }
            />
            <TextControl
                label={ __( 'Instancia', 'peertube' ) }
                value={ attributes.instancia }
                onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { instancia: val } ) }
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here the register block function (also [here](https://github.com/aitormendez/peertube/blob/master/src/index.js#L35-L97) in context):

```
registerBlockType( 'e451/peertube', {
    attributes: {
        identificador: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'text',
            selector: 'div',
        },
        instancia: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'text',
            selector: 'div',
        },
    },
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: __( 'Peertube video', 'peertube' ),
    description: __( 'Insertar contenido de peertube', 'peertube' ),
    category: 'embed',
    icon: 'video-alt3',
    supports: {
        // Removes support for an HTML mode.
        html: false,
    },
    edit: Edit,
    save,
} );
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you've doe a good job, but what about debugging - JS or PHP - can you capture and share any debug info you have?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that (I have no much experience). Query monitor plugin is not showing alerts and JS are linted with yarn build with no alerts too.

Comment: Your browser will have a code inspector with a JS console and you can activate PHP logging in WP https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log

Comment: Ok, thanks! Trying.

Comment: Indeed, I have an error in the JS console: Block validation: Expected attribute `src` of value `undefined/videos/embed/undefined`, saw `https://video.nogafam.es/videos/embed/2e3d35ba-f42f-49be-8bc2-97a770785570`.

Comment: Problem 3 is solved now. Question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad that you managed to fix the 3rd issue (block validation failed), and as for the first and second issues, you can fix them by using `useBlockProps` in your block's edit callback:

```js
// In src/index.js

import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            ... your code.
        </div>
    );
}
```

See [Developer Documentation → Block API Reference → Edit and Save](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/) in the block editor handbook for more details on that `useBlockProps` (hook). :)

Comment: PS: Sorry, I meant `src/edit.js`..